# How to pass value by ViewData to Editor Template by @Html.EditorFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata

In the view strongly typed view against `@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>`

I use inside a for-each loop:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
```

to render questions in a `Survey. It works flawless.

Now I would also like to pass additional data to the custom Editor Template. I did:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions, new { htmlAttributes = new { PersonId = 1000 } })
```

and then in the Edtior Template I want to refer to this `PersonId` and display it.

This is Editor Template I made(shortcut for question purposes):

```
  @using WebApplication2.Models
    @model   Question
    <div>
        @ViewData["PersonId"]
    </div>
```

but nothing shows up.

How to properly pass `PersonId = 1000` to this EditorTemplate.

Answer (score 21):

After some searching around found the following stack-overflow answer for iterating through nested properties. I was unable to get the cast to "dynamic" working, but using reflection correctly retrieved the nested anonymous object.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13981462/1046155

However, if you're determined to use HTML attributes only, you can specify them in a dynamic object:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions, new { PersonId = 1000, PersonName = "John", PersonAge=10, etc... })
```

And access them within the editor using @ViewData:

```
<div>
     @ViewData["PersonId"]
     @ViewData["PersonName"]
     @ViewData["PersonAge"]
     etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to do the same with **<editor asp-for=** tag helper?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@ViewData["htmlAttributes"]["PersonId"]
```

The outer anonymous object is what populates `ViewData`. Though, if you use the above, you need to take care that you check that `ViewData["htmlAttributes"]` actually exists before trying to reference "PersonId" off of it.

Comment: I pasted it and I get syntax error: `Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: Ok so I made investigation and lot of people have problem with it. It turns out it has to be added to view data by this method `@Html.ViewData.Add("PersonId",  here I need to instantiate object)` before `EditorFor`. The problem is I have no idead how to pass ANY second parameter there. I would like just to pass int `10` for example.

Comment: Ok I did `@{Html.ViewData.Add("PersonId", 100);}` there were syntax problems before but I don't know how to display it in the other view.

Comment: To use this method you must pass ViewData as follows: @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions, new { htmlAttributes = new { PersonId = 1000, PersonName = "John", PersonAge=10, etc... }}), and in the view check that ViewData["htmlAttributes"] exists

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you haven't set the `ViewData`. You need to set the `ViewData` in the controller that returns this View. Just `ViewData["PersonId"] = 10`

Comment: Then how to display it in view?

Comment: And why I can't add it in view by:`@{Html.ViewData.Add("PersonId", 100);}`?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032449/passing-extra-data-to-editortemplate

Comment: Not yet. I mostly tried this: http://www.codenoevil.com/pass-additional-viewdata-asp-net-mvc-4/

Comment: Ok your solution worked but why those @Html helpers did not. They are for some reason there... why they don't work.